# What is the best way to run a task in parallel without caring for the result?

Tags: python, asynchronous, async-await, python-asyncio

I'm learning python, and many times I see myself wanting to have a particular task be ran, without waiting for it in any way. For example, in one particular case, I want an instance of selenium webdriver to open, and at the same time have a warning window open, so I'd like to do something like calling an async function in Javascript, where the function is called, and does it's stuff while the rest of the code is running without noticing the other function was called.

From what i've studied, the way to do this kind of things in Python is with the asyncio library, but I haven't found a way to do quite what I'm trying, so far. From this [article](https://xinhuang.github.io/posts/2017-07-31-common-mistakes-using-python3-asyncio.html) I see a suggestion for solving a problem I usually have, which is `RuntimeWarning: coroutine foo was never awaited`. But I don't understand too well how to use the solution he proposes, which is:

```
prepare_for_foo()
task = loop.create_task(foo())
remaining_work_not_depends_on_foo()
loop.run_until_complete(task)
```

I would like to do this in a single function, something like:

```
def run_ignored(coroutine):
loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
task = loop.create_task(coroutine)
loop.run_until_complete(task)
loop.close()
```

But when I call it, it runs completely before anything else, which I guess makes sense, since loop is running until complete within the function. So how would I do what I want? The rest of the post talks about having a moment for loop to run remaining tasks at another time, but I can't figure what would be a good time for it. And preferably, I'd like to not have to add something to every function on which I want this feature, so that in that function loop has time to do it's tasks.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The easy way is to use threading.  `threading.Thread(target=foo)`.  As long as the thread spends most of its time blocked, threading works great.

Comment: Asyncio requires that: a) the task you want to run in the background is async (i.e. written as `async def` and awaiting stuff instead of running anything blocking), and b) the **rest of the program** is also async. In that case you would just run `asyncio.create_task(stuff_to_do_in_background())` and continue with your (async) code. But if either a) or b) is not the case, that won't be possible and asyncio will not be a good fit for you.